# UITabBarCrashes only when tabs are in a specific order

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, crash-reports

I have a UITabBarController with three views.  When I select View#2 the application crashes (see crash log).  If I reorder the tabs so that View#2 is first it works (No crash).

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib                   0x3368ef78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x359b8e90 CFRetain + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x359c2b74 +[__NSArrayI __new::] + 48
3   CoreFoundation                  0x359c2a8e -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 294
4   CoreFoundation                  0x359c27ce +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 38
5   CoreFoundation                  0x359c24f2 -[NSDictionary allValues] + 230
6   UIKit                           0x333e7f46 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 538
7   UIKit                           0x333563c0 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 240
8   UIKit                           0x33233c52 -[UIViewController loadView] + 82
9   UIKit                           0x331a9c10 -[UIViewController view] + 44
10  UIKit                           0x33209636 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 86
11  UIKit                           0x332095d4 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 24
12  UIKit                           0x33208f0e -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 294
13  UIKit                           0x3329244e -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 338
14  CoreFoundation                  0x359ca3f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
15  UIKit                           0x3318be00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
16  UIKit                           0x3318bdbc -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
17  UIKit                           0x332922d2 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 346
18  CoreFoundation                  0x359ca3f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
19  UIKit                           0x3318be00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
20  UIKit                           0x3318bdbc -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
21  UIKit                           0x3318bd9a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
22  UIKit                           0x3318bb0a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
23  UIKit                           0x33292062 -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 110
24  CoreFoundation                  0x359ca3f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
25  UIKit                           0x3318be00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
26  UIKit                           0x3318bdbc -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
27  UIKit                           0x3318bd9a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
28  UIKit                           0x3318bb0a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
29  UIKit                           0x3318c442 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470
30  UIKit                           0x3318a924 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 312
31  UIKit                           0x3318a312 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374
32  UIKit                           0x3317068e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350
33  UIKit                           0x3316ff34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
34  GraphicsServices                0x33762224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
35  CoreFoundation                  0x35a4451c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
36  CoreFoundation                  0x35a444be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
37  CoreFoundation                  0x35a4330c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
38  CoreFoundation                  0x359c649e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
39  CoreFoundation                  0x359c6366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
40  GraphicsServices                0x33761432 GSEventRunModal + 130
41  UIKit                           0x3319ecce UIApplicationMain + 1074
42  TecNotes                        0x000c2a28 main (main.m:18)
43  TecNotes                        0x000c2940 start + 32
```

There is no custom class or instance initialization. And the viewDidLoad method of View#2 does not seem to execute.

In an effort to debug the issue the viewDidLoad for View#2 has been reduced to the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSLog(@"Enter View#2 viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];

 NSLog(@"Exit View#2 viewDidLoad");
}
```

View#1 has similar logging to record that the viewDidLoad method is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSLog(@"Enter View#1 viewDidLoad");
[super viewDidLoad];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *cd = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
recipeName = [cd lastPathComponent];
NSString *basedir = [CategoryViewController getBaseDir];
int startPos = [basedir length]+1;
int len = [cd length]-startPos;
NSString *tmp = [cd substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPos, len)];

title = [CategoryViewController decode:tmp];

//self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = recipeName;
//self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = recipeName;
currentNote = 0;


//-------

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreen:)];
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedScreen:)];
swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

//-------

UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  back;
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  back;

[noteView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[NotesViewController getFontSize]]];

[self loadNotes];

 NSLog(@"Exit View#1 viewDidLoad");
}
```

Here is the resulting log entries.

Dec 16 11:42:21 Tonys-iPad TecNotes[6577] : Enter View#1 viewDidLoad

Dec 16 11:42:21 Tonys-iPad TecNotes[6577] : Exit View#1 viewDidLoad

Dec 16 11:42:27 Tonys-iPad ReportCrash[6580] : Formulating crash report for process TecNotes[6577]

Dec 16 11:42:27 Tonys-iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.bringardner.tecnotes[0x2bd8][6577]) : (UIKitApplication:com.bringardner.tecnotes[0x2bd8]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: The crash log isn't very useful. What code do you have in View#2's viewDidLoad or any init methods? Is there any code in View#1 that does anything to View#2?

Comment: In an attempt to debug this issue I have eliminated any initialization or code in vieDidLoad for View#2.

Comment: Here is what reminds - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSLog(@"Enter View#2 viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
     NSLog(@"Exit View#2 viewDidLoad");
}

Comment: I can't think of any other things to ask to diagnose this problem. If you can post your project somewhere, I can take a look at it, otherwise I'm out of ideas.